# Controls not showing during runtime

Tags: asp.net, css

I can see the changes in design time but the controls are not showing when the page is run... I have three such tags and other controls in a tab panel...

```
<a href="#" id="A1" class="small-heading">Change Password</a>
```

CSS:

```
.small-heading {
    background: url(../../Images1/small-heading.gif) no-repeat;
    width: 105px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #7a7a7a;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 0 3px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -127px;
}
```

WHat could be the problem?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. Can you add a larger sample, perhaps the parent elements until this link, and the styles relevant for those parents? Or maybe you can make a jsfiddle that shows the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure since you only have a partial code. Try to post the full code or simplified example.

I think because u use `overflow:hidden;` and `margin-left: -127px;`
try to remove `overflow:hidden;`

EDIT ***

Also you can't have width and height setup for a tag since by default a is inline. This may affect the background image too..
try to put `display:block` hope it solves the issue

Thanks

Comment: Its a huge code & I cant post it here...
Theres one thing: when I remove the css the tag is displayed, when I add the CSS, it doesnt. 
Also, its not showing the image in the background even in design time... How many ways are there for passing the image path..?

Comment: Ok, removing the margin helped partially. Now the tags (links) are displayed but it still doesn't take the image in the background...

Comment: Can you setup jsfiddle for this?